Why is Linux interrupting processing every second even with isolated core
I'm working in a real-time system Linux with the PREEMPT_RT kernel, multi-core Xeon processor.  I have an isolated core, and turned off irqaffinity and am using the nohz_full option on the isolated core.  I have set my priority to real-time aka SCHED_FIFO with a priority of 99.
I am trying to run a loop with bunch of simple computations that take about a millisecond.  I time that and run again indefinitely.  Even with all my attempts to gain full control of the scheduler, my processing is interrupted once a second for 50 milliseconds.  Both the 1 second interval and 50 ms pause are extremely regular.
I have verified that there are no interrupts happening on that core using cat /proc/interrupts.  The only thing changing is "Local timer interrupts" while my application is running, and nothing when it is not.
Why is this happening?  I can see that some Linux timer or scheduling tasks may need to run on that core eventually, but taking 50 ms to execute something seems quite excessive.
Any ideas on why this is happening and if there is any way to control it?

I discovered that there are 2 kernel parameters that control this behavior: /proc/sys/kernel/sched_rt_period_us and sched_rt_runtime_us.  Their default values are 1000000 and 950000, which exactly correlates with a 50 ms interruption every second.  This behavior can be controlled by modifying those values, including setting them to -1 to defeat this behavior entirely.

You need to use NOHZ_FULL for this isolated core to get rid of this.
Most out of the box kernels do not enable this option, you need to compile your kernel with CONFIG_NO_HZ_FULL=y. Then, pass an option nohz_full=comma-separated-list-of-isolated-cores to match your isolcpus=.... Also, setting rcu_nocbs=... will help.
Alongside with echo -1 > /proc/sys/kernel/sched_rt_runtime_us you will get a process with no interruptions ever.
